# My AVPlayer should not resume from last point for LIVE Streaming

Tags: ios, swift, stream, avplayer, live

I am establishing a Live stream player with `AVPlayer`. When I resume after pause, It resumes from last point. But Since it is a live stream I need my player to play back live, not the old point.

Comment: post some more details like what you've tried or what error you 're getting, if any..

Comment: This question has a solution in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42386328/22147

Comment: @RichardG Nothing error. In my player I pause the live stream(one FM) and play after some time. It's playing from the point i paused not the current one. that's the problem

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I already tried re initiating the player item. But it takes some seconds to load and that's not the proper way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you doing live streaming then your url should be m3u8 extension.here the complete steps of live streaming 
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: Okay. Now my stream link is mp3. So, If it is m3u8 I can overcome this. Thank u